# Design a component responsiveness on all the view ports

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, ionic3

**Component:**

*my-profile.html*

```
<div class="presentation margin-left-150">
  <img src="./assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" />
  <p>Hilda Isable Sanchez</p>
  <p>186579</p>
  <p>hilda.sanchez.gmail.com</p>
  <p>800.457.5687</p>
</div>
```

*my-profile.scss*

```
my-profile {
    .presentation {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        img {
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
        }
        .margin-left-150{
          margin-left: 150px;
        }
    }
}
```

**Page:**

*settings.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row class="header">
      <ion-col col-6>
        <my-profile></my-profile>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="details">
      <ion-col col-12>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*settings.scss*

```
page-settings {
    .content {
        ion-grid {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .header {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: color($colors, secondary);
        }
        .details {
            flex: 2;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks **good** on a mobile device like below:

[image]

But **Horrible** on iPad:

[image]

Can you please help me to design this correctly on all the viewports of the devices? In other words nicely centered `my-profile.html` component on all the device sizes (responsiveness).

**Note:** I know this was happened due to `margin-left-150`.But how can I center it properly?

Comment: One way if to set left: 50% and then transform: translateX(-50%) an easier way is to set text-align: center on the presentation class

Comment: Can you put it as an answer with more details? It is not clear for me.Thanks @Droid

Comment: i made a pen @Sampath https://codepen.io/droid-io/pen/GvxxRb

Comment: Not yet.This is what I can see on a mobile device with your changes:@Droid  http://i.imgur.com/pl6Hivb.png

Comment: Um, ok. If possible, could you make a js fiddle or pen with the whole code

Comment: Oh..That might be more complex task than my issue I think.How can I set `<my-profile></my-profile>` kind of inner component on such a tool? @Droid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center an `inline-block` element horizontally, you set its parent to `text-align: center`

*I also removed `width: 100%` from `presenation` or else it won't center being full width of its parent*

my-profile.html

```
<div class="presentation">
  <img src="./assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" />
  <p>Hilda Isable Sanchez</p>
  <p>186579</p>
  <p>hilda.sanchez.gmail.com</p>
  <p>800.457.5687</p>
</div>
```

my-profile.scss

```
my-profile {
    text-align: center;
    .presentation {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: left;            /*  reset to left align  */
        img {
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another option is of course Flexbox. With this you can also drop the `height: 100%` as flex items in a row direction by default fill their parent's height (`align-items: stretch`).

my-profile.html

```
<div class="presentation">
  <img src="./assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" />
  <p>Hilda Isable Sanchez</p>
  <p>186579</p>
  <p>hilda.sanchez.gmail.com</p>
  <p>800.457.5687</p>
</div>
```

my-profile.scss

```
my-profile {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    .presentation {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        img {
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you want a perfect centering. Just use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px #123;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Profile info</h1>
    <p> Text Text Text</p>
    <p> An other text An other text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apply to your code:

```
<ion-col col-12 class="parent">
    <my-profile class="child"></my-profile>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Nope.When I applied to my use case it shows like this on a mobile device.Please see that: http://i.imgur.com/rYLSGBM.png